# How to pass the json parse to Type variable with required field

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

With the `Request` type defined with `ID` attribute as required and `Name` as an optional:

```
export type MyRequest = 
  {
    ID: string, 
    Name?: string
  };
```

I go ahead and test it by passing it json-stringified `{ foo: "bar" }` which should be invalid for the `type MyRequest` since the required `ID` field is missing:

```
let jsonData = JSON.stringify( { foo: "bar" } );
let invalidData: MyRequest = JSON.parse(jsonData) as MyRequest;

console.log(invalidData);
```

Surprisingly it takes it fine with no errors.

Is this a bug or the `json.parse` overrides the `type` enforcement of the Typescript here?

Comment: How is it supposed to retain the type if you serialize it and deserialize it?

Comment: Please post an answer explaining why serializing and then de-serializing the data will result to Typescript to by-pass the required field validation so we could up vote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your typing is lost when you serialize your object as a plain `string`.

Keep in mind that TypeScript helps type code **before runtime** wherever it's statically analyzable. If you tell TypeScript that the result of `JSON.parse` is of type `MyRequest` it will assume this wherever you use `invalidData` but it won't check the type **at runtime** because this is not the purpose of TypeScript.

Comment: Even more so than "but it won't check the type at runtime because this is not the purpose of TypeScript", the types have already been erased by that point so it literally can't do that

Comment: Yes of course TypeScript types have no representation in JavaScript and they are not emulated in any way